# Eigenvectors of Matrix A

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

For a matrix Q prove the eigenvectors of kI-Q are equal to that of Q

Comment: Could you specify what $j,$ $k,$ $d,$ and $z$ are?

Comment: j is the root of -1, k and dz are constants

Comment: $k$ and $dz$ are **what** constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that the quantity "$4jk/dz$" is just a strange way to write a number, say $q$. So you are asking if $A$ and $q I-A$ have the same eigenvectors.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$, namely $A v= a v$. But $q I v = q v$, so you can conclude that

$$(qI-A)v = qIv-Av=qv-av = (q-a)v$$

As you can see, $v$ is also an eigenvector of $qI-A$ but the relative eigenvalue changes from $a$ to $q-a$.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes sense now!